# How to use xe:popupMenu

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'd like to have a right-click popup menu in an XPage. I therefore created a popup menu in XPages using the Extension Library. The menu doesn't display, whatever I try. Do I have to bind it to a button or so? If so, how??

Comment: If you want to use your xpage in client (XPiNC), right-click wont work.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it needs to be bound to a link or a button. The button or link needs to use Client-Side JavaScript to call the xe:popupMenu. There is an example in the Extension Library demo database, or more information in the XPages Extension Library book, chapter 8, p252.

Comment: Have neither book nor demo db. 

Correction: I have the demo db somewhere, but I was too lazy to go on a fishing expedition in the demo db... *sigh* I'll get my tackle...

Comment: Here's a link to the demo in OpenNTF hosted version of the Extension Library database: http://208.85.190.65/demos/demoextlib.nsf/Core_Outline.xsp

Comment: Ok, and now for the Right-click popup menu... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <xp:eventHandler event="contextmenu" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.openMenu(thisEvent,#{javascript:getComponent('pop1').getMenuCtor()})
    ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
```